# Unable to use "range" function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I need the range of a vector. From the MATLAB documentation, it says "For vectors, `range(x)` is the range of the elements." However, whenever I try to use it, I get the error "Undefined function 'range' for input arguments of type 'double'." For example, if I use `x=[1 2 3 4 5]` and then do `range(x)`, I will get this error. Am I crazy or is MATLAB screwing up here? I'm usually pretty good at figuring things out on my own but this one is stumping me.

Comment: Just a thought, my version of matlab is R2014a, could this function have been released after my version?

Comment: `range` is in the Statistics toolbox. Do you have that toolbox? Type `ver` or `help stats` in your Command Window. As per the documentation, `range` goes back to pre-R2006a. It's a very simple function that I'm sure you can write yourself, e.g., `range=@(x)max(x)-min(x);`.

Comment: Ah, that's it. Yeah, I ended up doing `max(x)-min(x)`. Seems kind of cheap that they wouldn't include that functionality in the base version since it's such a simple function, but I guess that's business.

Comment: @horchler write an answer!